# Extra output after every command running zsh in terminal

Tags: term

When running a command in the `*terminal*` in emacs, I always have the command I executed repeated twice with some extra text before the output of the command.

For instance:

```
$ echo "test"
2;echo1;echotest
$ cd ~/a_path
2;cd1;cd
```

Any idea why this might be happening? I'm using [yadr](https://github.com/skwp/dotfiles) for my zsh configuration (I'm trying out emacs from vim) and [spacemacs](https://github.com/syl20bnr/spacemacs) for emacs.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This appears to be your `zsh` config attempting to set the terminal title. It's common for shells to set the terminal title to the currently running command so you can identify when the command has completed. Emacs does not recognize the escape sequences used to set the terminal title (indeed, they are not standard and vary from terminal to terminal).

When I rolled my own `zsh` [title engine](https://github.com/PythonNut/zsh-config/blob/dev/modules/21_title.zsh), I ran into this. You can binary search your `zsh` config, and wrap the title bits in this:

```
if [[ -z ${EMACS+1} ]]; then
  # title stuff here
fi
```

Or, of course, you can remove them completely.